# Why we use subtract to represent distance

Tags: calculus

I am confused about that:
|x-y|= the distance between x and y

why do we use '-' to represent distance? Where does the principle come from?
I know that if y>0, x-y is exactly the distance; if y<0, x-y means you add the distance from the origin to y and x-y is the distance. But why is that? Somebody set this principle that we should use '+' present positive direction and '-' represent negative direction, and x-y represent reversing the negative to the positive then we can get the distance?
Maybe I am confused about '-' itself. Hoping get your answer! Thank you!

Comment: Because it gives the **difference** between to elements

Comment: @MorganRodgers: the diffence or disterance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is translation-invariant. For any constant $a$,

$$|x-y|=|(x+a)-(y+a)|.$$

---

It is also quite intuitive that when you are at point $x$ and travel a distance $d$, you get to $y=x+d$, hence $d=y-x$ !

Comment: Thank you! y=x+d is wonderful. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of one-dimensional space as a number line.

The  [**Ruler Postulate**](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/SegmentsAnglesTriangles/SATSegments.html#:%7E:text=Ruler%20Postulate,the%20difference%20between%20the%20numbers.) states that

> The points on a line can be put into a one-to-one correspondence (paired) with the real numbers. The distance between any two points is represented by the absolute value of the difference between the numbers.

On a number line, the number that corresponds to a point is called the *ordinate*. Suppose, for example, that point $P$ has ordinate $5$ and point $Q$ has ordinate $-2$. It's an abuse of notation, but we often write this as $P=5$ and $Q=-2$. (A point is not "equal to" a number, it "corresponds to" a number.).

The distance between points $P$ and $Q$ can be written as $d(P,Q)$. So the ruler postulate tells us that

$$d(P,Q) = |5 - (-2)| = |(-2) - 5| = 7$$

In general, this can be written as $$d(P,Q) = |P-Q|$$

If $x$ is a real number, then $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$. So we can write the above as

$$d(P,Q) = \sqrt{(P-Q)^2}$$

---

We can think of two-dimensional space as a coordinate plane.

How do we find the distance between two points $P$ and $Q$ on a plane? [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-analytic-geometry/hs-geo-distance-and-midpoints/a/distance-formula) is a derivation of the formula

$$d(P,Q) = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$$

for the distance between the points $P$ and $Q$ with coordinates $P = (x_1, y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$.

We can write

$$P - Q = (x_1, y_1) - (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2)$$

It is (well, used to be) common notation to express the length of the vector
$V=(x,y)$ as $\|V\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then the length of the vector $P-Q$ is
$$\|P-Q\| = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$$

It follows that $$d(P,Q) = \|P-Q\|$$

You should be able to see how this can be generalized to $n-$dimensional space.

---

By the way, the use of the double lines, $\|$, to distinguish between the number line and vector spaces in general is not required. $|P-Q|$ seems to be used just as often as
$\|P - Q\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much!